# Why isn't for loop resetting the range() function?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I have a code:

```
x = 6

for y in range(x):
    print(y)
    x -= 2
```

It gives: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

I wrongly predicted that it would give either of these 2 results:

1. `0, 0, 0`
   Since `x` goes from 6 to 4 to 2 to 0, there will only be 3 `y` printed. Also, to my understanding, after each loop, it goes back to the for loop statement, thus resets the range() completely and now every `y` is 0. I ran the code on PythonTutor and the pointer also seemed to go back to the loop statement after each loop.
2. `0, 1, 2`
   Since `x` goes from 6 to 4 to 2 to 0, there will only be 3 `y` printed. I thought it might be possible that while y takes on the value of the original range (i.e. 6), it would be limited by each new `x` and thus only have 3 `y` printed.

Possibility 1 was the most intuitive (albeit wrong) for me and I am not sure how to go about understanding why the answer is as such.

Comment: I wouldn't overthink this. This is just an idiom for doing for-loops in python. The range function is only executed once, before starting the loop.

Comment: Use a while loop if you need this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance of `range` produced by `range(x)` uses the value of `x` at the time `range` is called. It does not repeatedly check the value of `x` each time you need a new value from the range. Your code is effectively the same as

```
x = 6

for y in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
   print(y)
   x -= 2
```

Nothing you do to `x` has any effect on the `range` object being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` call creates a `range` object from `x` at the start of the loop. Changing `x` after this has no effect on the `range` object that is being used to iterate.

If you want to be able to change how many iterations you make in a loop, you probably want to look at using `while`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```py
# Firstly you assign 6 to the variable x
x = 6 

# 'y' will now be assigned to the numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] because the range is 'x' which is 6.

# by printing 'x' it will execute [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] but since x is 'x -2' which is the same as  '6 - 2'  it will print out the number 6 and -2 until it gets to the range which is -6. the output will be 6 numbers [6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4] 


for y in range(x):
    print(x)
    x = x - 2

# i am showing you a way of making it give you your expected output [6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4]
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to explain what this code does, and how it answers the question?

Comment: The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers. It behave as a generator. y will be assigned 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: thats what i mean